# Logical negation of ByteTensor in torch

Tags: lua, logical-operators, torch

Is there a way of taking a logical negation (i.e. performing a NOT operation) on a `ByteTensor` in Torch:

```
th> a = torch.rand(4)

th> a
 0.5786
 0.5271
 0.0090
 0.8859
[torch.DoubleTensor of size 4]

th> b = a:le(0.5)

th> a[b]
0.001 *
 9.0080
[torch.DoubleTensor of size 1]

th> -- How to select all "other" elements of a?
th> -- a[~b] or a[!b] or a[b:neg()] don't work.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Via [torch.ne](https://github.com/torch/torch7/blob/master/doc/maths.md#torchnea-b) (not-equal):

```
 a[b:ne(1)]
```

**EDIT**:

Or equivalently via [torch.eq](https://github.com/torch/torch7/blob/master/doc/maths.md#torcheqa-b):

```
 a[b:eq(0)]
```